# Why Eval("ID") doesn't work in the asp:LinkButton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asplinkbutton

My codes are

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
 PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("~/WebForms/AnaEkran_EPDK.aspx?id={0}", Eval("ID")) %>' >
</asp:LinkButton>
```

and

```
<a href="~/WebForms/AnaEkran_Bayi.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ID") %>" >.....</a>
```

and they don't work. On the linkbutton output is a javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton1', ''), why doesn't id take?

Answer (score 0):

go for `OnClientClick`  of link button

**from code behind**
put this in page load

```
LinkButton1.OnClientClick = "window.location = '~/WebForms/AnaEkran_EPDK.aspx?id="+ ID.toString() + "'; return false;"
```

**Or in aspx do this**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
 OnClientClick="goToYourPage();" >
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: it works but link look like this http://localhost:18675/WebForms/AnaEkran_EPDK.aspx?id=__Page so where is id? And i don' want to do this on the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute to your LinkButton:

```
 href='<%#"~/WebForms/AnaEkran_Bayi.aspx?id="+Eval("ID")%>'
```

Comment: LinkButton doesn't has a href attribute, when i put this to anchor link still doesn't work.